# Do you know why my grid isn't working as I am expecting?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Background Information:
I am trying to make a Tower Defense game in python in order to better understand visual python programs like Turtle and PyGame. I am currently using the turtle package and I am trying to make a test grid which is 7 by 7. I am being experimental with my code, so it might be a little messy.

Problem :
I can't get the grid to work right. Do you know how I could fix this issue?

Other Things To Keep in Mind:
At the moment, there is only one square drawn on the turtle screen. I believe the for loop should be drawing a squares along the y coordinates or rows and then moving right along the columns. I need a grid instead of one square being drawn. Keep in mind the turtle shape doesn't have a border around it.

Past Issues:
In the past, I have received an issue where the grid draws blocks at inconsistent locations along the y axis. This problem went away when I changed the code.

WindowClass1

```
import turtle
class Window1 :
    def __init__(self, width, height, startx, starty, turtle):
        self.width   = width
        self.height  = height
        self.startx   = startx
        self.starty = starty
        self.turtle = turtle
        
        #Sets the title of the screen
        turtle.title("Bloons Tower Defense Game")
        #Sets background color of the screen
        turtle.bgcolor("white")
        #Sets the size and position of the screen
        turtle.setup(width, height, startx, starty)
    def GetTurtle(self):
        return self.turtle*
```

BlockClass1

```
import turtle
#Should I make the block class extend the turtle class?
#This way the Block class will have the same properties as turtle with some additional properties like x, y, width, height, IDGround, IDAir
#I think I need to have the block class inherit the turtle class 100%
class Block():
    blockturtle = turtle.Turtle()
    def __init__(self, x, y, size, Id):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.Id = Id

    def GetXCoor(self):
        return self.x
    
    def SetXCoor(self, x):
        self.x = x
    
    def GetYCoor(self,y):
        return self.y
    
    def SetYCoor(self, y):
        self.y = y

    def GetSize(self):
        return self.size

    def SetSize(self, size):
        self.size = size

    def DrawBlock(self):
        self.blockturtle.penup()
        self.blockturtle.speed(0)
        self.blockturtle.pendown()
        if(self.Id == 0):
            self.blockturtle.color("red")
        elif(self.Id == 1):
            self.blockturtle.color("green")
        turtle.register_shape("test_square", ((0,0),(0,self.size),(self.size,self.size),(self.size,0)))
        self.blockturtle.shape("test_square")
        #Creates Duplicates of the blockturtle object.  THis way we aren't changing data for the same turtle each time.
        self.blockturtle.stamp()

    def DrawGrid(self, row_count, column_count):
        self.blockturtle.setpos(self.x,self.y)
        for c in range(column_count):
            for r in range(row_count):
                self.SetXCoor(-300 + (c*self.size))
                self.SetYCoor(-100 + (r*self.size))
                self.DrawBlock()
```

Main File

```
import sys
import turtle
import numpy as np
from WindowClass1 import Window1
from BlockClass1 import Block

#I only need a turtle object when I am wanting to draw a turtle
#Bg stands for background image

#Used to speed up the speed of complex graphics.  It will basically draw on the screen n number of times.
screen = turtle.Screen()

GameWindow = Window1(800, 600, 20, 7, screen)

row_count = 7
column_count = 7
count = 0

block = Block(-300,-100,20,0)
block.DrawGrid(row_count, column_count)

#This keeps the turtle objects drawing on the screen
turtle.done()
```

[image: Picture of My Output]

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing *functional* turtle with *object-oriented* turtle which always leads to confusion.  Here's a simplified, one file, implementation of your code that I believe does what you want:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class Window:
    def __init__(self, width, height, startx, starty, screen):
        self.screen = screen

        # Sets the title of the screen
        self.screen.title("Bloons Tower Defense Game")
        # Sets background color of the screen
        self.screen.bgcolor('white')
        # Sets the size and position of the screen
        self.screen.setup(width, height, startx, starty)

    def registerSquare(self, name, square):
        self.screen.register_shape(name, square)

class Block(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, x, y, size, color, window):
        super().__init__()

        self.size = size

        window.registerSquare("test_square", ((0, 0), (0, self.size), (self.size, self.size), (self.size, 0)))

        self.shape("test_square")
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.penup()
        self.setposition(x, y)
        self.color(color)

    def getSize(self):
        return self.size

    def setSize(self, size):
        self.size = size

    def drawBlock(self):
        ''' Creates images of the block object.  This way we aren't changing data for the same turtle each time. '''

        self.stamp()

    def drawGrid(self, row_count, column_count):
        for c in range(column_count):
            for r in range(row_count):
                self.setx(c * self.size - 300)
                self.sety(r * self.size - 100)
                self.drawBlock()

row_count = 7
column_count = 7

screen = Screen()

window = Window(800, 600, 20, 7, screen)

block = Block(-300, -100, 20, 'red', window)

block.drawGrid(row_count, column_count)

screen.mainloop()
```

Here `Block` uses your `Window` instance rather than relying on the `Screen` instance or the turtle functional API.  `Window` *has a* screen, whereas `Block` *is a* turtle.  Both valid approaches.